# Phonegap Directory Listing - List all from a directory

Tags: android, cordova

I've recently updated my version of phonegap, and my filebrowser I've made has stopped working.

I used to be able to list all the files in a folder like this:

```
// I normally get this from entries.fullPath, and cut it down to the first forward slash
var myLocation = "/testFolder";

var myDirectory = new DirectoryReader 
myDirectory.path = myLocation

myDirectory.readEntries(gotFiles, onError);  

function gotFiles(entries) {
   console.log(entries[i]);
}

function onError(e){
   console.log(e)
   return false;
}
```

This no longer works and returns an error code of 5.

I can get the (full) file path of a directory, what's the correct way of listing files now?